# Multiplying by vectors to assess covariance is zero

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, matrix

I want to prove the following but am unsure how.

Show that if:

For all fixed vectors $c$, $Cov(X,c'Yc) = 0$

Where $X$ and $Y$ are matrices of random variables, then it must be true that:

$Cov(X,Y)=0$

The above was a supposedly trivial step in a proof I was working through but, although the above makes completely intuitive sense, I feel I need to see a mathematical proof to believe it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please provide a link/reference to the source?

Comment: I cannot, no. The source is not publicly available.

Comment: thanks. and just to clarify, did you mean random vectors for X and Y or they indeed are matrices?

Comment: Hint: consider the cases $c=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ and $c=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0,\pm1,0,\ldots,0).$  Note that it suffices to prove this result for a *scalar* $X$ (representing any entry of the matrix $\mathbf X$).